# Iterated MapReduce job has NumberFormatException error

Tags: java, hadoop, exception, mapreduce

My program runs multiple Map reduce jobs, one for every line of parameters in the parameters file that I am passing to it.

The main function is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create configuration
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        if (args.length != 3) 
        {
            System.err.println("Usage: KnnPattern <in> <out> <parameter file>");
            System.exit(2);
        }

        //Reading argument using Hadoop API now
        conf.set ("params", (args[2]));
        String param = conf.get("params");
        StringTokenizer inputLine = new StringTokenizer(param, "|");

        int n = 1;
        while(inputLine.hasMoreTokens())
        {

            conf.set("passedVal", inputLine.nextToken());

            //Job Configuration here

            ++n;
        }}
```

The main function reads the 3rd argument, i.e., the Parameters file stored in HDFS and passes 1 string of parameters for each MapReduce job that it runs.
Or at least that is what I wanted it to do. I am not a 100% sure if this is completely right.

The setup for my Mapper looks something like this:

```
        protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
            // Read parameter file using alias established in main()
            Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
            String knnParams = conf.get("passedVal");

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(knnParams, ",");

            // Using the variables declared earlier, values are assigned to K and to the test dataset, S.
            // These values will remain unchanged throughout the mapper
            K = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            normalisedSAge = normalisedDouble(st.nextToken(), minAge, maxAge);
            normalisedSIncome = normalisedDouble(st.nextToken(), minIncome, maxIncome);
            sStatus = st.nextToken();
            sGender = st.nextToken();
            normalisedSChildren = normalisedDouble(st.nextToken(), minChildren, maxChildren);

    }
```

My parameter file contains this:

> 67, 16668, Single, Male, 3|40, 25000, Single, Male, 2|67, 16668, Single, Male, 3

That is 3 sets of inputs separated by '|'.

The run time error that I get is this:

> Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "/KNN/PARAMS/paramFinal.txt"
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
>       at KnnPattern$KnnMapper.setup(KnnPattern.java:168)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
>
> Container killed by the ApplicationMaster. Container killed on
>   request. Exit code is 143 Container exited with a non-zero exit code
>   143

From what I can gather, this looks like a typecasting error(?) and I am not sure how and why that is happening.

This code was mostly what I got from here - https://github.com/matt-hicks/MapReduce-KNN/blob/master/KnnPattern.java

It runs just fine for a single set of parameters but I need it to run for several parameters or test cases at once for further application.

Any way to fix this or at least any idea why exactly I am getting this error?
Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Before doing K = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); make sure that the value actually represents a number. It would help to see more of the exception stacktrace, not just the first line

Comment: Look at stacktrace you got. It is going to print exactly at what line do you try to interpret some random string as number. (KnnPattern.java:XY)

Comment: @Guillaume I tried to make K a constant (k=5) and I removed that part of the input from the params file just to make sure that wasn't the issue and I got the same error. I added the complete error log from this section to my post.

Comment: @GergelyBacso That is the part where a custom DoubleString type is defined (complete code here - https://github.com/vinitS101/knn/blob/master/KnnPattern.java). Since I left that class as is, I am not sure what changes it may require. Any help would be much appreciated. I am kind of new to this so sorry if it's a dumb thing to ask. :)

Comment: @vinit144 the question is not dumb, but you _are_ making it difficult to help. :) What is the linenumber? Don't say "around there", you have an exact linenumber in the exception. 1. Identify the location. 2. See what variable is being processed there. 3. Print the variable content out _before_ processing. 4. Take a look at it and you will see that it is not a number.

Comment: @GergelyBacso Sorry about that. It is in the DoubleString definition of the code (which is a custom Writable to pass Double and String values from Mapper to Reducer). I added the code to my github repo and linked it in my comment.  public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException
   {
    out.writeDouble(distance);
    out.writeUTF(model);
}

I am not sure how and why this affected the MR job to cause this exception. I have been playing around with this code for a while now trying to figure out a way to iterate it. The DoubleString definition was never a problem for single test cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why I was getting the NumberFormatException.

The problem was that I read the 3rd arguments (args[2]) as a string instead of a file location in HDFS which is why the error log says:

For input string: **"/KNN/PARAMS/paramFinal.txt"**

What I am doing right now for testing purposes is that instead of giving a file location, I am directly passing the input text as the 3rd argument. This helped me get rid of this specific error.

```
$ hadoop jar poker00.jar KnnPokerhand /Poker/train.txt /PokerOutputs/Output00 1,1,1,13,2,4,2,3,1,12,0/3,12,3,2,3,11,4,5,2,5,1/1,9,4,6,1,4,3,2,3,9,1
```

Hope this helps anyone who has this issue in the future. Cheers.